# Regex pattern to match only two characters between commas in Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

so for example in this string "3F, 4B, AA, A4B" I want a regex pattern that would be able to capture 3F, 4B, and AA. The amount of characters between the commas has to be 2. The only exception is that if both the characters are numbers we don't want to accept. We also do not care about white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this lookahead regex:

```
\b([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]|\d[a-zA-Z])(?=\s*,)
```

- `\b` is for word boundary.
- positive lookahead, `(?=\s*,)` to assert there there is following `,` after 2 characters.
- `([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]|\d[a-zA-Z])` to ensure we use at least one alphabet in 2 characters

in Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\d]|\\d[a-zA-Z])(?=\\s*,)");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yZ5zU2/1)

Comment: Thank you so much! I just have one follow up question.... is it possible to have this regex accept the entire string (including commas) if all the values in between the commas are valid? (2 characters, at least one is alphabetical)

Comment: You can use [`\b(?:(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]|\d[a-zA-Z])\s*,\s*)+`](https://regex101.com/r/yZ5zU2/2) to match full string including commas. Also you don't need to remove acceptance mark to be able to ask a question. You can leave comments here and I will try to answer whenever I'm online even after accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex:

```
\b(\d[a-z]|[a-z]\d|[a-z]{2})(?=\b)
```

This will capture only two letter composed of either alpha numeric or alpha only.

See demo at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uO3hS7/1)